# DI. Login action is not hit after adding Interface to AuthController constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP Core + Angular app. Default ASP DI container.   I am trying to implement DI with [Scrutor](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) in ConfigureServices:

```
services.Scan(scan => scan.FromCallingAssembly().AddClasses().UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip).AsSelf().WithTransientLifetime()); 
bool isThereClass11 = services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(Class11));
```

It seems working: isThereClass11 returns true.

Next I try to inject IClass11 in constructor: `public AuthController(IClass11 cl){}`

As result Login action is not hit and I got "zone.js:2969 POST https://localhost:44362/api/auth/login 500" on frontend.

```
public class Class11: IClass11 {}
public interface IClass11 {}
```

If AuthController constructor has no argument the Login action get hit and works as expected. 
How can I inject dependency in my AuthController preferably using Scrutor (I do not want to add dependencies manually in ConfigureServices nor use another DI unless I really need it ) ?

Comment: You only assert that `services` knows of `Class11` type, not of `IClass11` (because it was registered using `AsSelf()`). Hence, when your controller is expecting `IClass11` implementation, it won't be provided. Have you tried to register with `AsSelfWithInterfaces()` instead?

Comment: @haim770 Thank you! It worked, I really needed to read [docs] (https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/#registering-implementations-as-a-service) more carefully. Please create an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `services` only knows of `Class11` type but knows nothing about `IClass11` interface. That's because you registered it using the `AsSelf()` method.

Then, when your controller constructor is expecting an `IClass11` implementation, it can't be satisfied.

If you'll register your dependencies with the `AsSelfWithInterfaces()` method instead, it should work.

See [Source](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor/blob/master/src/Scrutor/IServiceTypeSelector.cs#L42)